# Splitting the string , mapping and building the sql in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have some task to do and can't figure out how to reach the result.

For example i have some STRING like this :

```
key1=value1&key2=value2|key3=value3
```

This string like key=value with options AND or OR.

I have also some map that contains following things:

```
key1=ke1Mapped; key2=key2Mapped; key3=key3Mapped;
```

I want to build some sql `Select * from table1 where`
And insert mapped keys and its values, but also to take into account & and | , i.e. AND or OR to use in sql query when it's needed.

Actually, finally sql query should be:

```
Select * from table where ke1Mapped=value1 AND key2Mapped=value2 OR key3Mapped=value3
```

I tried to split the main string and convert to MAP and then to loop over the list of mapped values and build dynamically sql. But i don't know what is AND or OR.

Tried to push it in two stacks , also were complicated.

I try now to understand how to build only architecture of this flow. And can't figure out what approach is needed here.
Anyone can suggest something?
Thanks

Comment: Why do you need the intermediary map (`key1=key1Mapped; key2=key2Mapped; ...`)?

Comment: Actually, when application got keys and values, then i need to map these keys to mapped keys that you wrote like key1=key1Mapped.  i store these mappers in table. I fetch them, then do some logic to map and then want to create a sql but with new mapped keys. Values remain the same for these keys.